# AngularJS: Trying to display content using ng-repeat, but page is shown to be blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is the page where I'm trying to display content. It's showing up blank. My application is a single page application, so most of the code is in the index.html file

verbPractice.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Practice verbs here</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="sentence in listOfSentences">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>{{sentence.first}} {{sentence.second}} {{sentence.third}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This page is linked to from another page called verbSelect.html. Here is the relevant code from that page

```
    <div class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="app.verbPractice" ng-click="storeInfo(); generateSentences()">Submit</div>
```

Both the above pages are under the same controller called verbController:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('arabicApp')
    .controller('verbController', ['$scope', 'verbFactory', 'pronounFactory', 'attachedFactory', function($scope, verbFactory, pronounFactory, attachedFactory){
        //Gets verbs from server
        $scope.verbArray = verbFactory.getVerbs().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.verbArray = response;
            }
        );

        //Gets pronouns from server
        $scope.pronouns = pronounFactory.getPronouns().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.pronouns = response;
            }
        );

        $scope.attached = attachedFactory.getAttached().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.attached = response;
            }
        );

        //Stores the array of selected verbs
        $scope.selectedVerbs = [];
        $scope.numSelectedVerbs = 0;

        //Searches theArray for name and returns its index. If not found, returns -1
        $scope.searchArray = function(theArray, name) {
            for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
                if (theArray[i].name === name) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };

        //Adds verbs to selected list
        $scope.addToSelected = function(theVerb)  {
            var num = $scope.searchArray($scope.selectedVerbs, theVerb.name);
            var divToChange = document.getElementById("verbSelect_"+theVerb.name);
            if (num > -1) {                                             //Found. Remeove it from selectedVerbs
                $scope.selectedVerbs.splice(num, 1);
                divToChange.className = divToChange.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)listItemActive(?!\S)/g , '' );
                $scope.numSelectedVerbs = $scope.numSelectedVerbs - 1;
            } else {                                                    //Not found. Add it in
                $scope.selectedVerbs.push(theVerb);
                divToChange.className += " listItemActive";
                $scope.numSelectedVerbs = $scope.numSelectedVerbs + 1;
            }
        };

        //Stores how many practice questions the user wants
        $scope.howMany = 0;

        //Stores what tense of verbs the user wants
        $scope.verbTense = "Both";

        //Stores what form the user wants
        $scope.verbVoice = "Both";

        //Include commands?
        $scope.includeCommands = false;

        //Sentense that will be generated
        $scope.listOfSentences = [];


        $scope.generateSentence = function(isCommand, theTense, theVoice) {
            var sent = {"first": "", "second": "", "third": ""};

            var attachedPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*14);
            var attachedToUse = $scope.attached[attachedPicker].attached;

            var pronounPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*14);
            var pronounToUse = $scope.pronouns[pronounPicker].pronoun;
            sent.first = pronounToUse;


            var verbPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.numSelectedVerbs);
            var verbToUse = $scope.selectedVerbs[verbPicker][theTense][pronounToUse];


            if (isCommand === true) {
                sent.second = verbToUse;
            } else {
                if (theVoice === "Passive") {
                    if (theTense === "Past") { sent.second = "were"; }
                    else { sent.second = "are"; }
                    sent.third = verbToUse;
                } else {
                    sent.second = verbToUse;
                    sent.third = attachedToUse;
                }
            }
            return sent;
        };

        $scope.storeInfo = function() {
            localStorage.setItem("howMany", $scope.howMany);
            localStorage.setItem("verbTense", $scope.verbTense);
            localStorage.setItem("verbVoice", $scope.verbVoice);
            localStorage.setItem("includeCommands", $scope.includeCommands);
        };

        $scope.getStoredInfo = function() {
            $scope.howMany = localStorage.getItem("howMany");
            $scope.verbTense = localStorage.getItem("verbTense");
            $scope.verbVoice = localStorage.getItem("verbVoice");
            $scope.includeCommands = localStorage.getItem("includeCommands");
        };

        //Generates sentences using the variables from verbSelect
        $scope.generateSentences = function() {
            $scope.getStoredInfo();
            var tensePicker;
            var voicePicker;
            var doCommand;
            var rand;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.howMany; i++) {
                //Picks the verb tense
                if ($scope.verbTense === "Both") {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random());
                    if (rand === 0) { tensePicker = "Past"; }
                    else { tensePicker = "Present"; }
                } else {
                    tensePicker = $scope.verbTense;
                }

                //Picks the verb voice
                if ($scope.verbVoice === "Both") {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random());
                    if (rand === 0) { voicePicker = "Active"; }
                    else { voicePicker = "Passive"; }
                } else {
                    voicePicker = $scope.verbVoice;
                }

                //If the voice is passive, use past tense
                if ($scope.verbVoice === "Passive") { tensePicker = "Past"; }

                //Determines if the sentence will be a command sentence or not
                if ($scope.includeCommands === true) {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                    if (rand === 0) { doCommand = true; }
                    else { doCommand = false; }
                } else {
                    doCommand = false;
                }

                var sentence = $scope.generateSentence(doCommand, tensePicker, voicePicker);
                $scope.listOfSentences.push(sentence);
            }
            console.log($scope.listOfSentences);
        };
    }])

;
})();
```

The variables: howMany, verbTense, verbVoice, isCommand, are set on this verbSelect.html page using ng-model. Both the verbSelect.html page and verbPractice.html page are under the same controller.

Everything seems to be working fine. At the end of my generateSentences() function, I output $scope.listOfSentences to the log, and it shows up without any problems, the array is being populated just fine. However, in my verbPractice.html page, nothing is showing up except the `<h1>` heading. For some reason, even though the $scope.listOfSentences array is populated, ng-repeat doesn't seem to be looping. Does anyone have any idea why?

Sorry for the long post

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer this question!

Comment: even though two states share the same controller, when state changes, data won't keep.

Comment: @Pengyy: Thanks.I know. That's why I wrote the storeInfo() and getStoredInfo() functions. When I log the listOfSentences in the generateSentences() function, it is logged correctly, so I think the information is being carried over. Though, maybe I'm mistaken. In that case, how do I keep the information when the state changes? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think you should create a service to hold both the list of sentences and the logic to generate it. This way you can inject `sentenceGenratorService` or whatever you call it and for the button do `sentenceGenratorService.generateSentences()` or create a method on the controller to pass the variables that you currently store in localStorage, and for the ng-repeat simply `sentenceGenratorService.listOfSentences`. Services are the common approach to shared logic and/or state in angular.

Comment: @cYrixmorten: So Services  don't reload when state is changed? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Exactly  no problem, happy coding